# BigQuery - How can I compute an average window by window?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have a table looking this:

[image]

I am trying to compute an average number of orders for each client, every 3 month.
I am not looking to compute a moving average month by month but an average of the previous 3 months, every 3 month.

Example: here, the client first ordered in March 2022. I want the average number of orders from march to may (0+2+2) / 3 = 1.33. Then, I want the average from june to august (4+4+5) / 3 = 4.33 etc.

I want to render a table with 1 row = average for 1 window.
For this example:

| id_client | period | nb_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201904 | 2022-03-01 - 2022-05-01 | 1.33 |
| 201904 | 2022-06-01 - 2022-08-01 | 4.33 |
| 201904 | 2022-09-01 - 2022-11-01 | 6.33 |

Thank you very much for any help/hints given!

Answer (score 0):

A less complicated and more scalable approach to this is to breakdown your date related dataset. For example: YEAR, QUARTER, MONTH and DATE. This way you'll have flexible options in aggregating your data periodically, you can simply query a table having YEAR, QUARTER and AVG_ORDERS as your data set.

RAW DATA:

| year | quarter | month | date | id_client | dt_first_day_of_month | nb_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Q4 | 11-Nov | 2022-11-04 | 201904 | 2022-11-01 | 0 |
| 2022 | Q4 | 12-Dec | 2022-12-24 | 201904 | 2022-12-01 | 2 |
| 2023 | Q1 | 01-Jan | 2023-01-05 | 201904 | 2023-01-01 | 2 |
| 2023 | Q1 | 02-Feb | 2023-02-27 | 201904 | 2023-02-01 | 4 |
| 2023 | Q1 | 03-Mar | 2023-03-08 | 201904 | 2023-03-01 | 5 |
| 2023 | Q2 | 04-Apr | 2023-04-26 | 201904 | 2023-04-01 | 6 |

QUARTER_QUERY:

```
SELECT year, quarter, id_client, avg(nb_order) as avg_orders FROM tb_source ORDER BY year ASC GROUP BY year, quarter, id_client
```

| year | quarter | id_client | avg_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Q4 | 201904 | 1 |
| 2023 | Q1 | 201904 | 3.67 |
| 2023 | Q2 | 201904 | 6 |

From this example you can easily derive numerous approaches on how you want to aggregate your numbers and probably use some visualizations for dashboard or reporting purposes.

Hope this helps.